# How can i execute a shell script and close my app in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, shell

I would like to run a shell script from my cocoa app when clicking on a button. I can easily use the system() call to do that, but that's not all i need. I need the app to close as soon as it calls the script, or even before it calls the script. Basically the script should take a few seconds to run so i need the app to close by that time. The reason i need this is because i'm writing a simple application that puts the mac to sleep, but before that it does lots of cleaning up via a shell script and i basically don't want this app to be open when i brind the system back from sleep.

Would using a fork or something like that do the job or do i need some special magic to do this?

Thank you

Comment: I imagine fork would do fine. Just fork and make whatever calls you need to to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use popen() instead of system().  The init process should inherit ownership of the script you run once your application exits.  You could also fork/exec, but popen will be simpler as its semantics are much closer to that of system().

Answer (score 1):

If you're in Cocoa, you'll want to use [NSTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  If your script needs admin privileges, there's always [STPrivilegedTask](http://sveinbjorn.org/STPrivilegedTask).